# How to save an array of text in PostgreSQL using Django model.?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-postgresql

I am trying to save an array of text containing category types for a hotel system which looks something like this `['category-1', category-2', category-3, category-4]` . I am using `category_type = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200),null=True)` in my models.py

The error i get is

> malformed array literal: "" LINE 1: ..., '{category-1,
>   category-2}'::varchar(200)[], ''::varcha...
>   ^ DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.

The error persist even after processing python list from `['category-1', category-2', category-3, category-4]` to `{category-1, category-2, category-3, category-4}`. 
I have gone through postgresql documentation and have found very limited help,
https://pganalyze.com/docs/log-insights/app-errors/U114 this is something similar posted to what i am facing problem with.

Could someone please tell me what am i doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Following is in my View.py

```
hotel_category=categoryTable(category_type=categorytype)
hotel_category.save()
```

and i am using `categorytype=request.POST.getlist('category-type')` in my Views.py to get it from the POST request after user submits the form. This returns a Python list that i have mentioned above, i have manipulated this list to match PostgreSQL ArrayField with '`{','}'` but i still have this error. If there is anything else you would like me to add, please let me know. :)

Comment: Can you include the actual code where you're assigning the values to `category_type` and invoking the `save()` method?

Comment: @FlipperPA i have Edited my question and added further details at the end :)

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: @mattjegan Django version 2.2.2

Comment: Did you guys have a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

This is an update/answer to my question for anyone who faces this issue in the future. After struggling to find help from different resources, i decided to use JSON string to store my python list.

I am using :
`categorytype = json.dumps(request.POST.getlist('category-type'))`
to encode and using `JSONDecoder()` to fetch from database and decode. I have no idea how would this impact my further development but for now it seems a decent approach since personally i think ArrayFields are not well supported and documented in Django.

I will keep this post updated as i progress further on how this approach has impacted my development.

Have a nice day.